# Spring with JBoss - JBoss5AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext is not of type ConfigurableWebApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, jboss

I'm trying to run a Spring web application (4.3.13 version, with jdk 1.6 and maven 3.0.4) with JBoss (AS 5.1).

I know that "Spring Framework 4.0 removed support for JBoss AS 5's VFS variant" ([click here for the article](https://github.com/arey/spring4-vfs2-support#jboss-vfs-2-support-for-spring-framework-40)).

So, I follow the instructions in the article. But I'm getting this error:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Custom
>   context class
>   [com.javaetmoi.core.spring.JBoss5AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext]
>   is not of type
>   [org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext]
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:377)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
>     at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
>     at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:362)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>myApp</display-name>

  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

  <!-- README: https://github.com/arey/spring4-vfs2-support#jboss-vfs-2-support-for-spring-framework-40 -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>com.javaetmoi.core.spring.JBoss5AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>it.myApp</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value> classpath:configuration-myApp.xml </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>  

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>it.myApp.rest.impl</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>   
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>
             it.myApp.rest.validation.mapper.ValidationExceptionMapper
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```